# how to form a group of same values using Hash Map

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

i  retrieve data from Array list . Already Array list have a value are same as Hash Map Types (key ,values); After retrieve those data from Array list  and mapping into the  Hash Map variables. i have to group those by a variable called tax.

1) Add the add in Hash map

```
 HashMap<String, String> personq = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                personq.put("product_id",tv4);
                                personq.put("productname",tv2);
                                personq.put("exit",exit);
                                personq.put("product",product_1);
                                personq.put("unit_price",tv3);
                                personq.put("tax", String.valueOf(gst));
                                personq.put("purchase_cost",String.valueOf(tv9));
                                personq.put("cost", String.valueOf((two.format(finalcp))));
                                final_cart_list_1.add(personq);
```

After that adding those Hash Map values into Arraylist called **final_cart_list_1**  type of initialization of array list

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> final_cart_list_1;
```

Creating another hash map to store the values from **final_cart_list_1**

```
 HashMap<String, String> personMap = new HashMap<String, String>();



for(int i=0;i<final_cart_list_1.size();i++){
                    personMap = final_cart_list_1.get(i);// getting values from arraylist and storing into hashmap
                    Log.d("valuesinHashamap ",""+personMap);
                    tax = Float.parseFloat(personMap.get("tax"));
                    Log.d("tax_values",""+  tax);
                    qty=Integer.parseInt(personMap.get("qty"));
                    Log.d("qty_values",""+qty);
                  unitprice=Float.parseFloat(personMap.get("unit_price"));
                    Log.d("untiprice_values",""+qty);
                  }
```

**all the operation done in Cart basis. i had 4 product in cart** 
below i posting logcat values for **personMap** hashMap

```
2019-08-07 18:08:35.501 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/valuesinHashamap: {product_id=500, unit_price=220.000000, exit="1", cost=281.60, purchase_cost=200.0, productname=System(or)Laptop/ANTIVIRUS/K7/asd/test, qty=1, tax=28.0, product="0"}
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/valuesinHashamap: {product_id=501, unit_price=126.250000, exit="1", cost=161.60, purchase_cost=101.0, productname=System(or)Laptop/ANTIVIRUS/K7/asd/test1, qty=1, tax=28.0, product="0"}
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/valuesinHashamap: {product_id=500, unit_price=220.000000, exit="1", cost=281.60, purchase_cost=200.0, productname=System(or)Laptop/ANTIVIRUS/K7/asd/test, qty=1, tax=28.0, product="0"}
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/valuesinHashamap: {product_id=500, unit_price=220.000000, exit="1", cost=281.60, purchase_cost=200.0, productname=System(or)Laptop/ANTIVIRUS/K7/asd/test, qty=1, tax=28.0, product="0"}
```

after that i take product particular tax values for all product

```
  tax = Float.parseFloat(personMap.get("tax"));
```

log cat values for tax is in below

```
2019-08-07 18:08:35.501 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/tax_values: 28.0
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/tax_values: 28.0
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/tax_values: 28.0
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/tax_values: 28.0
```

after that i take product particular quantity ,unit prices values for all product as same as tax only .

Quantity logcat

```
2019-08-07 18:08:35.501 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/qty_values: 1
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/qty_values: 1
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/qty_values: 1
2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/qty_values: 1
```

unit prices logcat

```
 2019-08-07 18:08:35.501 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/untiprice_values: 1
    2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/untiprice_values: 1
    2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/untiprice_values: 1
    2019-08-07 18:08:35.502 13378-13378/com.example.dewsys.technicianapp D/untiprice_values: 1
```

after that i need to create an array or array list . (Basic concept is group product by tax and calculation of the taxes .  )

if the tax values are same we need to add those tax,quantity,unit prices  together and push into created array or array list.

if  the tax values doesn't matched they want to add separately want to add with quantity and unit prices together and push into created array or array list.

**i have a algorithm in step by step**

1. getting the tax value .
2. first time entry into the loop directly we want to push data like quantity,tax,and unit prices by group of tax .

3.Second time entry into the loop check the current tax values and previous tax values . if the current and   previous tax values is then we want to add the tax ,quantity,unit prices of previous  and current tax ,quantity,unit prices together . else the current and previous tax is not matched separated want to add it and append separately  by new group of  tax values

Guys i'm  new to java programming . i have ideals what i projected above by algorithms or hint  . So kindly help to solve this problems  by which approach

Comment: I just want to make myself clear, you want to group details based on tax, if tax value same as previous adding means old+new or [old,new,..]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you on your work

```
       List<Map<String, String>> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> stringStringMap = new HashMap<>();
    stringStringMap.put("tax", "123");
    stringStringMap.put("quantity", "1");
    stringStringMap.put("prices", "123");

    Map<String, String> stringStringMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    stringStringMap2.put("tax", "123");
    stringStringMap2.put("quantity", "1");
    stringStringMap2.put("prices", "123");

    Map<String, String> stringStringMap3 = new HashMap<>();
    stringStringMap3.put("tax", "1234");
    stringStringMap3.put("quantity", "1");
    stringStringMap3.put("prices", "123");

    strings.add(stringStringMap3);
    strings.add(stringStringMap2);
    strings.add(stringStringMap);
     Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> tax = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        o -> o.get("tax"), Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println(tax);
```

This will print out put somewhat like this

```
{123=[{quantity=1, tax=123, prices=123}, {quantity=1, tax=123, prices=123}], 1234=[{quantity=1, tax=1234, prices=123}]}
```

Here all taxes having value `123` grouped together and `1234` grouped seperately.

Feel free to comment or ask questions
Thanks